# How can I send a message with a lot of images and text in a telegram chat like in the template below?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I am trying to write a telegram bot.
I want that my bot sends a message like in the following template with a lot of images and text. But I can't figure out which method is responsible for this. What is the correct approach to implement it?
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1G56EdNRn8X5m7uBJ5LrYfVG-JYPyAzNg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write your text inside telegram the way you want it, then copy it to your ide. Almost all editors support emojis. But in case your doesn't, you can always use this website:

https://unicode.org/emoji/charts-12.0/full-emoji-list.html

The method to be used is send message.

Comment: Thank you If I right understood It is impossible to send your custom picture in the message with your custom size instead of emoji?